# Print .doc (NOT docx) without opening Word JAVA

Tags: java, printing, doc

I have a Java application which create some .doc (not .docx! no HTML inside) documents which I need to print.

The PC which will run the program has to print all documents created this way, but no MS Word is installed in that machine, nor is possible to install it (or openoffice or anything).

Is there a way to send it direcly to the printer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can print a microsoft word doc using any of the printing api by directly sending document to printer queue. You may want to check openoffice DocumentPrinter api.

Check sample code [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java/Office/DocumentHandling#DocumentPrinter).

```
        // Setting the property "Name" for the favoured printer (name of
        // IP address)
        com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue propertyValue[] =
            new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue[1];
        propertyValue[0] = new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue();
        propertyValue[0].Name = "Name";
        propertyValue[0].Value = args[ 0 ];

        // Setting the name of the printer
        xPrintable.setPrinter( propertyValue );

        // Setting the property "Pages" so that only the desired pages
        // will be printed.
        propertyValue[0] = new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue();
        propertyValue[0].Name = "Pages";
        propertyValue[0].Value = args[ 2 ];

        // Printing the loaded document
        xPrintable.print( propertyValue )
```